# Image rendering from Wamp server to android Application

Tags: android, json

My android application is caching an images from this address
"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mobilesiri/Android-Custom-Listview-Using-Volley/master/images/Bill_Gates.jpg"

But it is not caching and showing the images from my wamp server's address which is
http://localhost/RightF/Upload/15.png

Through API this address looks like
"image":"http://localhost/RightF/Upload/15.png

I even dont get any error.

Comment: Use IP addresss instead of `localhost`

Comment: Nice story. Any questions?

Comment: Question is why it is hapenning so ?

Comment: I am using Genymotion and standard IP http://10.0.3.2/RightF/Upload/15.png
I am getting all other text response and the address as a string but not getting the image

Comment: Thanks @BNK it worked